# MFC: member variable vs resource id of control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am new to vc++. I want to know which is proper and efficient way of handling controls by using member variable or resource id of controls.

```
m_Name.SetWindowTextW(_T("xyz"));
or 
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT2,_T("xyz"));
or 
CWnd* cwd =    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT2);
cwd->SetWindowTextW(_T("xyz"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The efficient way is to create a control member variable. You can do this in the resource editor by right-click on the control and select Add Variable.

Every time you use GetDlgItem with the resource ID then it iterates through all child controls to find the one with the specified ID. This iteration is inefficient when done for every GetDlgItem call.

Comment: I was curious, so, I looked into the MFC code (winocc.cpp).  I can't seem to see where it iterates over all of the child windows.  Does that happen within the nested API call?

Comment: Yes, it has to do it in the API call.  And, it has to do it when you make a member variable as well--just the one time.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Can you point me to some documentation that shows that?  I was under the impression that MFC maintains an internal table (map) of window handles for that purpose.

Comment: MFC does have an internal map of window handles.  However, in a dialog, you attach control member variables to controls on the dialogs using the DDX_Control() macro.  One of the arguments for the DDX_Control() macro is the dialog item ID.  Internally, it eventually calls the Windows API function GetDlgItem() that returns the HWND for the window with the requested ID.  To do that, the API function has to enumerate the child windows and return the HWND of the window that first matches the control ID.  After that, the glue of MFC subclasses and attaches the HWND to the CWnd control.

Answer (score 1):

You should be concerned about what is more maintainable over the long run instead of efficiency unless you really have a performance bottleneck.  It's probably not something to worry about in a SetWindowText() operation.

You have to ask questions like

1) How many times are you going to set the window text?  Just once or multiple times?  If once, you should probably just use SetDlgItemText().

2) Are you going to do other operations besides just setting the text?  If so, then probably make it a member variable.  If not, then what is the point of making it a member variable and subclassing the window?  To save a millisecond the user will never notice?